# Problem with flex-box vertical align middle (align-items: center)

Tags: css, flexbox

I'd like the navigation arrows to align vertically middle.

On the [live site](https://mandoemedia.com/templates/) they are off-center.

[image]

There is compromising CSS I can't change which sets a `top: 40%` for the arrows (`.owl-nav button`).

I've tried `unset`ing their top, but this pushes them to underneath the image.

I've tried setting `top: calc(50% - 37.5px);` (minus half the button's height of `75px`) but this is off-center. Is my math right here?

I've been able to get it working below by using a fixed height for `.owl-nav.pp-carousel-nav` but on the [live page](https://mandoemedia.com/templates/) the `.owl-item`s are not of fixed width and height, they are responsive.

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
  position: relative;
}
.pp-content-post-carousel {
  position: relative;
}
.landscape-carousel-container {
  width: 100%;
}
.landscape-carousel-content {
  width: 100%;
}
.landscape-carousel-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 236px;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .4s ease !important;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #22a1d9;
}
.landscape-carousel-img {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 236px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(14,34,129,0);
  background-image: url("https://cdn-ehbod.nitrocdn.com/MnwLQZiWrxfKgQoPapfeSJHycGHMrPjW/assets/static/optimized/rev-315e7f6/img/background-image.svg");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #dfefef;
}
.owl-nav.pp-carousel-nav {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 242px;
  width: 370px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
.owl-nav button {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: none !important;
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.owl-nav button.owl-prev {
  left: -15px;
}
.owl-nav button.owl-next {
  right: -15px;
}
.owl-nav button svg {
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.sr-only {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 370px;">
  <div class="pp-content-post pp-content-carousel-post pp-grid-custom post-6474 templates type-templates status-publish hentry templatecategory-hospitality templatecategory-landscape-liquor-hospitality-2 templatecategory-liquor" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork" data-id="6474" style="visibility: visible; height: 269.2px;">
    <div class="landscape-carousel-container">
      <div class="landscape-carousel-content">
        <div class="landscape-carousel-overlay">
          <a href="https://mandoemedia.com/templates/hospitality/liquor/liquor-store-many-bottles-templates/" class="landscape-carousel-button w-button" rel="nofollow">Edit this Template</a>         </div>
        <div style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn-ehbod.nitrocdn.com/MnwLQZiWrxfKgQoPapfeSJHycGHMrPjW/assets/static/optimized/rev-315e7f6/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/landscape_Hospitality_Liquor_001.jpg&quot;);" class="landscape-carousel-img lazyloaded" nitro-lazy-bg="https://cdn-ehbod.nitrocdn.com/MnwLQZiWrxfKgQoPapfeSJHycGHMrPjW/assets/static/optimized/rev-315e7f6/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/landscape_Hospitality_Liquor_001.jpg"></div>
        <div>Liquor Store - Many Bottles</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-nav pp-carousel-nav">
  <button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-prev">
    <svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 192 512">
      <path fill="currentColor" d="M25.1 247.5l117.8-116c4.7-4.7 12.3-4.7 17 0l7.1 7.1c4.7 4.7 4.7 12.3 0 17L64.7 256l102.2 100.4c4.7 4.7 4.7 12.3 0 17l-7.1 7.1c-4.7 4.7-12.3 4.7-17 0L25 264.5c-4.6-4.7-4.6-12.3.1-17z" class=""></path>
    </svg>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-next">
    <svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 192 512">
      <path fill="currentColor" d="M166.9 264.5l-117.8 116c-4.7 4.7-12.3 4.7-17 0l-7.1-7.1c-4.7-4.7-4.7-12.3 0-17L127.3 256 25.1 155.6c-4.7-4.7-4.7-12.3 0-17l7.1-7.1c4.7-4.7 12.3-4.7 17 0l117.8 116c4.6 4.7 4.6 12.3-.1 17z" class=""></path>
    </svg>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is caused by the navigation elements parent box. It also includes the text below - therefore, you don't center it relative to the image, but to the image & its descriptive text. As you probably cannot change the html structure here I suggest you simply change the css calculation by to something like `top: calc(50% - 45px);`

Comment: That fixed it, thanks @Frnak, add an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer as stated in the comment:

The problem is caused by the navigation elements parent box. It also includes the text below - therefore, you don't center it relative to the image, but to the image & its descriptive text. As you probably cannot change the html structure here I suggest you simply change the css calculation by to something like

```css
top: calc(50% - 45px);
```

Answer (score -2):

The `height` of the `button` is 66px and positions in relation to the `div` with `class="pp-content-post-carousel pp-equal-height clearfix"` which is 33.19px taller than the images.

Comment: So what's the answer to the problem then?

Comment: Preventive downvote. lol. There is no question really. He misread the buttons width for the height and I assume he didn't realize what it positions in relation to. To me that's answer enough. It's not even about flex-box like his title suggests.

Comment: Then don't post it as answer but use the comments. This is not a preventive downvote as I'm not going to answer this question.
I just think the answer does not fit the question (as you already mentioned).

Comment: Fair enough. I don't think any answer fits the question. It basically boils down to "No your math is not correct and this (my answer) is why.

Comment: I'd like to move to flexbox and avoid a hard-coded top value as the elements are fluid.